# discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 0): 404: Not Found

Tags: python, discord.py

i have this code:

```
    class Adduser(discord.ui.Modal, title="add"):
        answer = ui.TextInput(label = "ID de l'utilisateur à ajouter au ticket", style = discord.TextStyle.short, placeholder = "ID", required= True)
        
        def __init__(self, channel):
            self.channel = channel
            super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, user=answer):
            member = await interaction.guild.fetch_member(user)
            if "ticket-de-" in interaction.channel.name:
                await interaction.channel.set_permissions(member, view_channel=True, send_messages=True, attach_files=True, embed_links=True)
```

but i have this error:

```
2022-11-18 08:35:47 ERROR    discord.ui.modal Ignoring exception in modal <Adduser timeout=None children=1>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\distool\env\scripts\bot.py", line 422, in on_submit
    member = await interaction.guild.fetch_member(user)
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 2094, in fetch_member
    data = await self._state.http.get_member(self.id, member_id)
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 740, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 0): 404: Not Found
```

Someone can help me?

The user is on the server and i'have tried to copy his id for the test but the client doesn't find him

Comment: Where is your `answer` variable coming from?

Comment: Also, there‘s no other argument being passed other than `interaction` in `on_submit`

Answer (score 0):

Got it now.

You are using the Modal in the wrong way. You only get `interaction` being passed. Also, the `answer` variable contains a modal instance. You could just pass `int(user.value)` to `fetch_member()` but that wouldn‘t be proper python syntax

instead use

```py
async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    member = await interaction.guild.fetch_member(int(self.answer.value))
    # Rest of your code goes here
```

You should add error handling in case the user isnt found or a not valid ID was entered

Comment: Hello, thank you there is no more error in the terminal but when I submit the response, the modal tells me that an error has occurred and to try again
I'm sorry, I'm really struggling with modals

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but what exactly is your error now?

Comment: The modals telle me to retry because an error has occured, I have the impression that he does not recognize the user's id yet he is present on the guild

Comment: If it's in the modal it self, then its pretty easy. You have to respond to every interaction that discord is sending to you. Just use `await interacion.response.defer()`. Also, check if the permissions were set, or add a print statement

Comment: thanks, the modal tells me that there is an error but still add user to the ticket